# Postgresql Update with subquery

Tags: postgresql

```
UPDATE Customer C
SET name = B.name, 
age = B.age
FROM (SELECT A.*, B.* FROM CUSTOMER_TEMP WHERE A.ID = B.ID) AS B
```

I got a sql as above, after I run the query, it update all my rows to the same result.

I wonder I need a where after

```
UPDATE Customer C
SET name = B.name, 
age = B.age
FROM (SELECT A.*, B.* FROM CUSTOMER_TEMP WHERE A.ID = B.ID) AS D
WHERE C.ID = D.ID
```

But i got this id is ambiguous for the last query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update Customer set
    name = B.name, 
    age = B.age
from Customer as C
    inner join CUSTOMER_TEMP as B on B.ID = C.ID
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9e8a1/1)